# UITableView with Search bar as inputView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have textfield which shows an tableview on its inputview and returns value on select I added a searchbar to tableview but the problem is, when I tap to searchbar tableview automatically closing and re-opening which means i cant even click searchbar. Any advice?

Here is the code.

```
class myClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    //the all are in viewdidload
    var tableView: UITableView  =   UITableView()
    tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44))
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent
    searchBar.placeholder = " Search..."
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.translucent = false
    searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    searchBar.delegate = self
    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

    tableView.tableHeaderView = navigationBar

    toTextField.inputView = self.tableView

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on Text field , your text field becomes first responder. Since you mentioned   toTextField.inputView = self.tableView; so you table view appears.

As soon as you click search bar, Now Search bar is first responder. Since TextFIeld is no more first responder hence table View Disappear.

One solution can be:
do not make table view as input view to text field. that is :
   //toTextField.inputView = self.tableView

Instead you can present table view controller by using one of delegate method of TextField:

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)   {
    let test : UITableViewController = UITableViewController.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    test.tableView = self.tableView
    let testNav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: test);
    self.presentViewController(testNav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```